# Not able to click on button in LinearLayout inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am building a quiz app. At the initial quiz screen I want one instruction screen that tells the user to tap anywhere to proceed with next question. To achieve this I took a `FrameLayout` and stuffed two `LinearLayout`inside it. The first `LinearLayout` contains the quiz screen. The second `LinearLayout` contains the instruction screen with a button (**lets call this button as `Ok Button`**). I want to dismiss the instruction screen when user clicks on this `Ok Button`. The problem is that I am not able to click `Ok Button`. It shows no physical reaction (like button press) etc when user taps on it, neither it fires its `onClick` method.

I have also set the `android:clickable="true"` for the second `LinearLayout` so that it responds to user clicks instead of passing it onto the first `LinearLayout`

I can't understand what's wrong with my code. Can anyone please help me with the situation. I am stuck on this one real bad.

---

### **Here's my xml** (**button id is : `got_it_button`**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:paddingBottom="0dp"
             android:paddingLeft="0dp"
             android:paddingRight="0dp"
             android:paddingTop="0dp"
             android:background="#4285f4"
             android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
             tools:context=".ui.OptionsQuizActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:background="#33000000"
            android:id="@+id/darkQuestionBack"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qusTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_question"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:textColor="#aaffffff"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp">


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Option One"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/optionButton0"
                android:background="@drawable/semi_white_button"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Option Two"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/optionButton1"
                android:background="@drawable/semi_white_button"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Option Three"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/optionButton2"
                android:background="@drawable/semi_white_button"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Option Four"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/optionButton3"
                android:background="@drawable/semi_white_button"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_instructions"
        android:background="#dd000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/instruction_text"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="#ddffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Okay"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/got_it_button"
            android:background="@drawable/semi_white_button"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

---

**And the Java Code:**

```
package sprintingminds.com.countrycapitalquiz.ui;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import model.ColorGenerator;
import model.QuizGenerator;
import sprintingminds.com.countrycapitalquiz.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class OptionsQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout mDarkQuestionBack, mInstructionsLayout;
    private FrameLayout mMainLayout;
    private Button mOptionButton0, mOptionButton1, mOptionButton2, mOptionButton3, mGotItButton;
    private String mOption1, mOption2, mOption3, mOption4;
    private TextView mQusTextView;
    private QuizGenerator mQuizGenerator;
    private ColorGenerator mColorGenerator;
    private boolean mNextQuestionCounter, mFirstRunCounter;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaCorrect, mMediaWrong;
    private ValueAnimator mBackDarkColorAnimator, mBackLightColorAnimator, mBarColorAnimator ,mQuestionFadeInAnimator, mQuestionFadeOutAnimator;
    private ValueAnimator mButtonFadeOut,mButton1FadeIn, mButton2FadeIn, mButton3FadeIn, mButton4FadeIn;
    private String mNextQuestion;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_quiz);

        mNextQuestionCounter = false;
        mFirstRunCounter = true;
        mMediaCorrect = MediaPlayer.create(OptionsQuizActivity.this, R.raw.correct);
        mMediaWrong = MediaPlayer.create(OptionsQuizActivity.this, R.raw.wrong);


        // Initialize Views
        mMainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mDarkQuestionBack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.darkQuestionBack);
        mInstructionsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_instructions);
        mOptionButton0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionButton0);
        mOptionButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionButton1);
        mOptionButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionButton2);
        mOptionButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionButton3);
        mQusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qusTextView);
        mGotItButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.got_it_button);

        // Generating New Question and displaying on screen with Random Color
        mQuizGenerator = new QuizGenerator();
        mColorGenerator = new ColorGenerator();
        displayNextQuestion();


        // Initialize Ads
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-96012881833111111/3495512222");
                        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);


        //Setting On Click Listeners
        mOptionButton0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                checkAnswer(0);
            }
        });

        mOptionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                checkAnswer(1);
            }
        });

        mOptionButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                checkAnswer(2);
            }
        });

        mOptionButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                checkAnswer(3);
            }
        });


        mGotItButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Toast.makeText(OptionsQuizActivity.this,"It's Working!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        mMainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                if (mNextQuestionCounter){
                    mMediaWrong.stop();
                    mMediaCorrect.stop();
                    mMediaWrong.release();
                    mMediaCorrect.release();
                    mMediaWrong = MediaPlayer.create(OptionsQuizActivity.this,R.raw.wrong);
                    mMediaCorrect = MediaPlayer.create(OptionsQuizActivity.this,R.raw.correct);
                    try {
                        mMediaCorrect.prepare();
                        mMediaWrong.prepare();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        //do something when unable to play sound
                    }
                    displayNextQuestion();
                    toggleButtons(true);
                    toggleButtonState();
                    mNextQuestionCounter=false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void checkAnswer(int index){

        setButtonsAsUnselected();
        if(index!=mQuizGenerator.getCorrectAnswerIndex()){
            markWrongAnswer(index);
            mMediaWrong.start();
        }else{
            mMediaCorrect.start();
        }
        markCorrectAnswer(mQuizGenerator.getCorrectAnswerIndex());
        toggleButtons(false);
        mNextQuestionCounter = true;


    }

    public void markCorrectAnswer(int index){
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                mOptionButton0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answer_button);
                mOptionButton0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 1:
                mOptionButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answer_button);
                mOptionButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 2:
                mOptionButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answer_button);
                mOptionButton2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 3:
                mOptionButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answer_button);
                mOptionButton3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
        }
    }

    public void markWrongAnswer(int index){
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                mOptionButton0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer_button);
                mOptionButton0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 1:
                mOptionButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer_button);
                mOptionButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 2:
                mOptionButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer_button);
                mOptionButton2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
            case 3:
                mOptionButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer_button);
                mOptionButton3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                break;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButtonState(){
        mOptionButton0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.semi_white_button);
        mOptionButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.semi_white_button);
        mOptionButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.semi_white_button);
        mOptionButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.semi_white_button);
        mOptionButton0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        mOptionButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        mOptionButton2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        mOptionButton3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
    }


    public void toggleButtons(Boolean status){
        mOptionButton0.setClickable(status);
        mOptionButton1.setClickable(status);
        mOptionButton2.setClickable(status);
        mOptionButton3.setClickable(status);

    }

    public void displayNextQuestion(){
        int oldLightColor, oldDarkColor, oldBarColor;
        oldLightColor = mColorGenerator.getIntLightColor();
        oldDarkColor = mColorGenerator.getIntDarkColor();
        oldBarColor = mColorGenerator.getIntBarColor();
        mQuizGenerator.nextQuestion();
        mColorGenerator.generateNext();
        //Setting our next question and options
        mNextQuestion = mQuizGenerator.getQuestion();
        mOption1 = mQuizGenerator.getOptions(0);
        mOption2 = mQuizGenerator.getOptions(1);
        mOption3 = mQuizGenerator.getOptions(2);
        mOption4 = mQuizGenerator.getOptions(3);
        populateNewOptions();

        //Checking for first question
        if (mFirstRunCounter) {
            mMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(mColorGenerator.getIntLightColor());
            mDarkQuestionBack.setBackgroundColor(mColorGenerator.getIntDarkColor());
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(mColorGenerator.getIntBarColor());
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(mColorGenerator.getIntBarColor());
            }
            mQusTextView.setText(mNextQuestion);
            mFirstRunCounter = false;
        } else {
            fadeInOutNextQuestion();
            animateBackgroundColors(oldDarkColor, oldLightColor, oldBarColor, mColorGenerator.getIntDarkColor(), mColorGenerator.getIntLightColor(), mColorGenerator.getIntBarColor());

        }
    }

   /* public void fadeInOutOptions(){
        mButtonFadeOut = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f,0f);
        mButton1FadeIn = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,1f);
        mButton2FadeIn = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,1f);
        mButton3FadeIn = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,1f);
        mButton4FadeIn = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,1f);
        mButtonFadeOut.setDuration(250);
        mButton1FadeIn.setDuration(200);
        mButton2FadeIn.setDuration(200);
        mButton3FadeIn.setDuration(200);
        mButton4FadeIn.setDuration(200);
        mButtonFadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        mButton1FadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mButton2FadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mButton3FadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mButton4FadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mButtonFadeOut.start();
        mButtonFadeOut.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mOptionButton0.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton1.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton2.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton3.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        mButton1FadeIn.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mOptionButton0.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton1.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton2.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                mOptionButton3.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());

            }
        });
/*
        mButton1FadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){
                mButton2FadeIn.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){

            }
        });

        mButton2FadeIn.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mOptionButton1.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        mButton2FadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){
                mButton3FadeIn.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){

            }
        });

        mButton3FadeIn.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mOptionButton2.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        mButton3FadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){
                mButton4FadeIn.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){

            }
        });

        mButton4FadeIn.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mOptionButton3.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

    }*/

    public void populateNewOptions(){
        mOptionButton0.setText(mOption1);
        mOptionButton1.setText(mOption2);
        mOptionButton2.setText(mOption3);
        mOptionButton3.setText(mOption4);
    }


    public void fadeInOutNextQuestion(){
        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f,0f);
        mQuestionFadeInAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,1f);
        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mQuestionFadeInAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        mQuestionFadeInAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator.start();
        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mQusTextView.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        mQuestionFadeInAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                mQusTextView.setAlpha((float) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        mQuestionFadeOutAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){
                mQusTextView.setText(mNextQuestion);
                mQuestionFadeInAnimator.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator){

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){

            }
        });

    }

    public void animateBackgroundColors(int oldDarkColor, int oldLightColor, int oldBarColor, int newDarkColor, int newLightColor, int newBarColor){
        // Animating dark background color
        mBackDarkColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator() , oldDarkColor, newDarkColor);
        mBackLightColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), oldLightColor, newLightColor);
        mBarColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), oldBarColor, newBarColor);
        mBackDarkColorAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mBackLightColorAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mBarColorAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mBackDarkColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                mDarkQuestionBack.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        mBackLightColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                mMainLayout.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }

        });

        mBarColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            }

        });
        mBackDarkColorAnimator.start();
        mBackLightColorAnimator.start();
        mBarColorAnimator.start();
    }

    public void setButtonsAsUnselected(){
        mOptionButton0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_answer_button);
        mOptionButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_answer_button);
        mOptionButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_answer_button);
        mOptionButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_answer_button);
        mOptionButton0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#44ffffff"));
        mOptionButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#44ffffff"));
        mOptionButton2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#44ffffff"));
        mOptionButton3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#44ffffff"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: setting `clickable=true` to the parent layout means that it will handle the clicks, so they will never get to the child

Comment: Strangely if I copy my xml code to a new android project .. the button works with `clickable=true` for its parent layout .. so it means something is messy in my java code .. but I still can't figure it out :(

Comment: Compare the 2 java files. Use https://www.diffchecker.com